# How can I add new gestures to Intel RealSense SDK for SR300?

Tags: computer-vision, intel, gesture-recognition, realsense

So Intel realsense has a limited number of gestures. I am interested in adding more gestures. How can this be done? I couldn't find a tutorial for this. Here's a piece of code how they do it for existing defined gestures:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < firedGesturesNumber; i++)
            {
                PXCMHandData.GestureData gestureData;
                if (handAnalysis.QueryFiredGestureData(i, out gestureData) == pxcmStatus.PXCM_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
                {
                    PXCMHandData.IHand handData;
                    if (handAnalysis.QueryHandDataById(gestureData.handId, out handData) != pxcmStatus.PXCM_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
                        return;

                    PXCMHandData.BodySideType bodySideType = handData.QueryBodySide();
                    if (bodySideType == PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_LEFT)
                    {
                        gestureStatusLeft += "Left Hand Gesture: " + gestureData.name;
                    }
                    else if (bodySideType == PXCMHandData.BodySideType.BODY_SIDE_RIGHT)
                    {
                        gestureStatusRight += "Right Hand Gesture: " + gestureData.name;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(gestureData.name);

                }
```